# why I get this error : You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_3' with dtype float

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Hello I am new on tensorflow I try to run little function I wrote. I already reboot my kernel and  this is my script :

```
import tensorflow as tf
def phi1 (x,B,w) :
    x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
    W1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
    B1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None])
    phi = []
    x2 = tf.add(x1,x)
    W2 = tf.add(W1,w)
    y = tf.matmul(x2,W2)
    print(y.get_shape())
    for i in range(3):
        z1=tf.sin(y[i,:])*tf.transpose(B)
        Z2=tf.cos(y[i,:])*tf.transpose(B)
        z1= tf.cast(z1, tf.float32)
        z2= tf.cast(Z2, tf.float32)
        #print(type(z2))
        phi.append(z1)
        phi.append(z2)

    y = phi 
    return y
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3, 1])
W2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3])
b2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[3])
y = phi1 (x2,b2,W2)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    z4_op = sess.run(y , feed_dict = {x2: [[1.0],[2.0],[3.0]], b2: [0.5, 2.0, 1.0], W2: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]})
    print(z4_op)
```

the error is :

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_3' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_3 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op 'Placeholder_3'
```

Answer (score 4):

Well your function accepts **6** arguments:

```
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
W1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
B1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None])
```

and

```
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3, 1])
W2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3])
b2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[3])
```

in your `sess.run` you only specified three of them, thus computations cannot be performed.

Actually `B1` is only declared but never used, thus the only missing ones are `x1` and `W1`.